# Extracting text (from delim to end of line) from file - BATCH

Tags: batch-file, text, extract, delimiter

text file:

```
juicer test 1 2
next line
end
```

code:

```
for /f "delims=test tokens=1*" %%A in (file.loc) do echo %%B
```

what i am getting:

```
r test 1 2
xt line
ECHO is off.
```

what is expected:

```
test 1 2
```

Comment: `delims` is a **set** of characters, not a string, so your code is looking for a delimiters `t`,`e` or `s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q65836459.txt"

SET "string=test"

FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 IF "!line:*%string%=!" neq "%%a" ECHO %string%!line:*%string%=!
)
GOTO :EOF
```